# Why Android application is not visible in running application?

Tags: android

I am facing quite different issue.I had developed Android application it works fine.But the problem is I am not able to see that application in Running application (i.e. Setting > Application > Manage Application > Running). It is visible in rest of all the tab's (i.e. Downloaded,All). I am facing this issue in HTC Nexus 2.3.6 and in IceCreamSandwich.
Application is running fine without any issue.But the only problem is >

Why it is not visible.Any suggestion.......

Answer (score 0):

The Running Tab is only for apps that runs in background (e.g. Service, etc.), not for "normal" apps, even they are *suspended* in background, it doesn't mean that they *run* in background.

[Check out Android Developers blog post about this tab](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2010/02/service-api-changes-starting-with.html)

Comment: Yes you may be right but I am using AIDL interface which is used to play radio.So when I am running radio at that time also it is not visible.

Comment: Then I guess it is handled differently, to my knowledge, the running tab is only for Service though. Perhaps the interface does not use a Service to play its content, thus not displaying your app.

Comment: Ok my application is used to play songs by using player or radio in background at that time it should visible but unfortunately it is not visible at that time also.

Comment: I agree with you, since the stock Music app also have a Service running, showing in the tab when the music is playing, and your app should have a Service too. But in my opinion, don't worry about it if your app is running fine. :) Sorry that I cannot provide an answer to your question.